# Passing path parameters to AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm fairly new to AWS. I'm trying to pass a path parameter to my Lambda function like if I do a request:

```
PUT /users/{identity_id}
```

and pass in the the body below parameters

```
{
     "name": "shikasta_kashti",
     "age": 35
}
```

then I cannot get `event.identity_id` in my lambda function. I'm able to access `event.name` and `event.age` but not `event.identity_id`?

I think I would have to do some Mapping Template so I went to my PUT method and in Integration Request -> Mapping Templates added application/json and then selected Mapping Template (instead of Input passthrough) and entered this:

```
{
    "identity_id": "$input.params('identity_id')",
}
```

but I still cannot get `event.identity_id` in my Lambda function.

Comment: dumb question, did you deploy the API after adding the mapping template?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes I did deploy after the change (adding the mapping template.)

Comment: i just set up this scenario and it worked ok - so there must be something slightly off in the integration. Can you do a test run and then see what is shown in the log for "Endpoint request body after transformations" and "Endpoint response body before transformations?"

Answer (score 1):

Late response for someone stumbling on this...

The path params are included under `event.pathParameters`.
Given the request  `PUT /users/1` you would see a pathParameters object that looks like:

```
{
  "identity_id": 1
}
```

If you didn't call your function with `invoke` you'll find the rest of your params in the `event.body` hash as a string.

To access that you'll do:

`const { name, age} = JSON.parse(event.body)`

Comment: `event.pathParameters` exists only if "Lambda proxy integration" is enabled in API method.